# Python Linux - Convert latex file to pdf file

Tags: pdf, ubuntu, linux, python

I am using `python 3.5.2` and `ubuntu linux 16.04`.

I am trying to convert latex files to pdf - extension `.tex/.latex`.

I have tried using linux builtin `soffice` command and it didn't wenT well. 
Also looked at [PyLaTex][1] library and it seems that it convert `pdf to latex` but not `latex to pdf`.

How can i convert a LaTex file to a PDF file?

Comment: Use e.g. the pdflatex command from the command line.  Better yet, use a latex editor such as texstudio.  This is unrelated to python.

Comment: Not your question, but the following may not be off-topic [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner)

Comment: [PyLaTeX](https://github.com/JelteF/PyLaTeX) doesn't convert pdf to LaTeX, and strictly speaking it doesn't convert LaTeX to PDF either. It is, as I understand it, a package for generating LaTeX code in a Python interface. While it does have a `generate_pdf()` method, that just calls e.g. `pdflatex`, so having a LaTeX distribution like TeX Live installed is a prerequisite.

Comment: If you want to automate this process using Python, take a look at the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JPi using `pdflatex` worked.

Usage:

Installation -

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-base
```

At the cmd -

```
pdflatex sample.tex
```